# Retreiving facebook comments done on my different blogs using facebook comments

Tags: javascript, c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-graph-api

I have an asp.net application which contains multiple blog posts and I'm using facebook comments plugin and I want to implement 2 functionalities:
  1. Every time a user makes a comment on any blog I get a notification via some email or any other way.
  2. I can get a list of all comments made by every user on all of the blogs.

Though I have some vague idea regarding 1st functionality if someone can please clearly guide me on how to implement it and 2nd functionality as I don't have any clue for the implementation of 2nd point.

Comment: Not sure if what you want is possible at all. You can get the comments for a specific URL, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1603507626630008 - but that gets you message & created_time of a comment only, and `from` doesn’t seem to return anything here.

Comment: And I think you would have to poll this endpoint constantly to be able to realize when there’s new comments - the `comment.create` event previously provided via the JS SDK has been removed.